# What is pred/totalOrder in the ordering module?

Tags: alloy

**[Update]** Just for fun, I implemented `pred/totalOrder` in Alloy. Here it is:

```
sig elem {}

one sig Ord {
    First: elem,
    Next: elem -> elem
} {
    no a: elem | (a -> First) in Next   // First is the first atom in the list
    // Constrain Next to be ordered like Next in the ordering module
    (elem <: iden) & Next = (none -> none)   // Constrain Next to be irreflexive
    Next.Next & Next = none -> none  // Constrain Next to be intransitive 
    (Next & ~Next) = none -> none    // Constrain Next to be asymmetric
    Next + ~Next + (elem <: iden) != (elem -> elem)   // Constrain Next to be non-connected
    #(elem.Next) = #Next   // Constrain Next to be injective
    #(Next.elem) = #Next    // Constrain Next to be functional
    #Next = minus[#elem,1]  // Constraint Next to contain all atoms in elem
}

fun first: one elem { Ord.First }
fun next : elem->elem { Ord.Next }
fun last: one elem { elem - (next.elem) }
fun prevs [e: elem]: set elem { e.^(~(Ord.Next)) }
fun nexts [e: elem]: set elem { e.^(Ord.Next) }

pred Show {
    #elem > 2
}

run Show
```

The ordering module has this:

```
private one sig Ord {
   First: set elem,
   Next: elem -> elem
} {
   pred/totalOrder[elem,First,Next]
}
```

What is `pred/totalOrder`? Where is it defined? What does it do? Can I use it in my Alloy models?

What is `private`? Where is it defined? What does it do? Can I use it in my Alloy models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword *private* makes a signature invisible when the module is invoked, and can be used in any model. The pred/foo models are built-in and should not be used in user-level models.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how to open those pred/foo models?

Comment: @LoïcGammaitoni Just found [some utility models](https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/tree/master/org.alloytools.alloy.core/src/main/resources/models/util) and [this very specific code](https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/blob/master/org.alloytools.alloy.core/src/main/java/edu/mit/csail/sdg/ast/ExprList.java) for pred/totalOrder.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that its meaning is hardcoded in the tool, the same way that  fun/sub and fun/add are defined.

As to why remains unclear to me. Maybe for optimization sake?

Comment: Thanks @Loïc Gammaitoni